# How do you avoid mixing CHASSIS GND and sensor GND when reading a sensor?

Tags: microcontroller, sensor, ground, chassis

So I'm aware that in some systems they have different circuits with different grounds. For example, cars have at least a chassis ground and a sensor ground, and there is a measurable difference between the two. In fact, you are not supposed to treat one like the other. 
So my question is, if we have a 5v MCU reading a 5V sensor of a car, where do we ground our MCU? Sensor ground or chassis ground?
What if we now need to drive a mosfet, where would the source go? Sensor or chassis?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Lets examine a realworld design: a robot with several powerful drive motors, and an instrumentation system that monitors the motor bearing temperatures to detect wear and misalignment to predict wearout times and thus schedule preventative maintenance.

The motors are 48 volt at 20 amps (or about 1/2 horsepower).

The temperatures (bearing temp and outside temp) are to be measured with typeK thermocouples of 40uV/degree C, with 0.1 degree Centigrade resolution (which requires 4 microvolt resolution).

Suppose the ground system has 0.1 ohm resistance. The 2  motors, when running and drawing 40 amps total, causes 2 volts drop in Ground. Yet 1uS later that voltage drop could be ZERO volts.

So we need to keep the motor grounding separate from the sensor/quantization grounding.

You did not ask about magnetic fields, but as the 0/20/40 amps motor power is switched, predictably-large transient induced voltages are induced throughout your robot. I'll not discuss this any more, except to say TwistedPairs and "LocalBatteries" are your tools.

What does the robot system look like?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fBsJdZ.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Exciting, eh?

Comment: You write "Local Batteries" but you depict an isolation SMPS. Is there cases where you put seperate batteries in a system, just to be sure you have no supply transients?

Comment: thank you for question. I should have written "LocalBatteries" in quotes; I've used "LocalBatteries" to achieve local-charge-storage for high-speed power transients, for decades; as a kid, I had 100dB broadband (audio) experimental amplifiers (6 stages of bipolar gain) that would oscillate **UNLESS** I provided privately-filtered R+C low-pass VDD to first 2 or 3 stages of amplifier chain. The filtering was CRC, that is, a PI filter with resistor for series element. I no longer had oscillations; I could hear thermal-noise in my earphones. Here the several LC filters are the "LocalBatteries".

Comment: Notice the DC_DC converter (48v--5volt) breaks that GROUND path. Now we must break the high-frequency transient paths. So we have CLLC filters (with inductors in both GND and in power paths) for (1) the motor controller, using 1,000uF capacitor; (2) CLLC into the DC_DC converter, using 100uF cap; (3) CLLC into the LDO (to keep the DC_DC transient at 2MHz and at 200MHz ringing out of LDO) with 100uF cap; (4) CLLC between LDO (which has poor trash/spike/transient regulation at high frequencies) and the 24-bit quantizer.

Answer (score 1):

If your sensor has own GND, it also should have a own VCC. Most car engine controls have a seperate 5V pin.

If you use sensor GND and normal 12V VCC then use a big capacitance.

If you want to connect to other parts with chassis GND it becomes difficult.

To make it simple, I'd connect to the sensor GND and sensor VCC. If this is not possible I'd use any Chassis GND/VCC, which is convinient to connect. Then:

- connect the sensor via about 100 R and connect the Arduino input via about 4k7 to GND.
- Filter the sensor signal with C and/or L.
- Measure, if this is enough.

If the distortions are too big, you can use an optocoupler. That should be more simple solution than creating a new power supply for your µC.